# Evaluate $ \lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(x^{2}\left(1+2+3+\dots+\left[\frac{1}{|x|}\right]\right)\right) $

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Evaluate
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(x^{2}\left(1+2+3+\dots+\left[\frac{1}{|x|}\right]\right)\right)
$$
For any real number $a,|a|$ is the largest integer not greater than $a$.

I am getting no clue! from where to start!

Comment: Do you know what the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers is? It will help you calculate the answer.

Comment: Transfer the problem to infinity by replacing $x$ with $1/n$ and consider $n\to +\infty$ together with the hint by @paulinho

Comment: sorry, I am not getting! yeah n(n+1)/2 ..but here how can I apply that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
& \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {x^2 \left( {1 + 2 + 3 +  \cdots  + \left[ {\frac{1}{{\left| x \right|}}} \right]} \right)} \right)  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {\left| x \right|^2 \left( {1 + 2 + 3 +  \cdots  + \left[ {\frac{1}{{\left| x \right|}}} \right]} \right)} \right)
\\ &
 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\left( {1 + 2 + 3 +  \cdots  + n} \right)} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{n(n + 1)}}{{2n^2 }} = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first $n$ integers is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.  Now, we can express $n$ with the limit of $\big \lfloor \frac{1}{|x|} \big \rfloor$.
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \frac{\big \lfloor \frac{1}{|x|} \big \rfloor \left(\big \lfloor \frac{1}{|x|} \big \rfloor+1\right)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks for the correction, I edited it.